# WCAG 2.0 H44 - How to add label when textbox uses placeholder text

Tags: html, wcag2.0

For H44, complying with Success Criteria (1.1.1, 1.3.1, 3.3.2 and 4.1.2) requires me to add 'label's for `input` textboxes. However, when the textbox's label text is within the textbox itself as a placeholder, how can we meeting these criteria?

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

For example, if you scroll to the footer/bottom of https://www.goorin.com/ , you'll see a textbox for subscribing to their email newsletter, and there is the placeholder text within the textbox "Enter your email address". This IS the label text. I can't add an actual visible label without altering the design of the page/footer to have label text outside of the textbox? Even if I make the label hidden via CSS, it will not comply with 3.3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `placeholder` attribute for a label is specifically pointed out in the html spec as a bad thing to do.  See the `warning` under the [placeholder spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute).  Many screen readers will not read the placeholder.  Its use is supposed to give a clue as to the format of the data you need to enter into the field, not the label of the field.

WCAG 3.3.2 says a label is typically needed but if the context of the `<input>` gives a clue as to what the label should be, then a **visible** label may not be needed, but you still need a hidden label for the screen reader.